# regex lookahead n times python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following sentence as an example

```
isaac morka morka morka
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
isaac morka
```

i tried the following code:

```
re.findall(r'isaac[\s\w]+(?=morka)', 'isaac morka morka morka')
```

but the result obtained is not correct

```
['isaac morka morka']
```

Comment: Give another example of your desired output, what should be the output when the input is something like: "isaac some random string morka"

Comment: for example the following string "isaac things anything morka morka morka isaac letters morka morka". The expected result should be ['isaac things anything morka','isaac letters morka'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your regex `isaac[\s\S]+?morka` without using lookaround.

Test the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/bmp5pH/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
rgx = r'\bisaac\b|\bmorka\b(?!.*\bmorka\b)'
```

```
str = 'isaac morka morka morka'
```

```
re.findall(rgx, str)
  #=> ["isaac", "morka"]
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZBKbM4MTFZITe/KDsRmVTi4ipKrwAqKFKPSQKriUmqiUkCy8Ukadgr6mnBeZrqXFwFRZl5JRpFqXppmXkpiTk5GkDdOgpAOzQ1uf7/BwA)<sup><sub><-</sub></sup><sub>\(ツ)/</sub><sup><sub>-></sub></sup>[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ecgq0S/1)

Let's break down the regular expression.

```
\bisaac\b   # match 'isaac' with word boundaries fore and aft
|           # or
\bmorka\b   # match 'morca'  with word boundaries fore and aft
(?!         # begin negative lookahead
  .*        # match zero or more characters
  \bmorka\b # match 'morca' with word boundaries fore and aft
)           # end negative lookahead
```

---

---

If a list of unique words is to be returned such that each word in the list appears at least once in the string one could write the following.

```
str = "isaac morka louie morka isaac morka"

rgx = r'\b(\w+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)'

re.findall(rgx, str)
  #=> ['louie', 'isaac', 'morka']
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZBKbM4MTFZITe/KDtRISe/NDMVykYSV@LiKkqvACouUo9J0ogp19YEUvaKeloxSTGGMUma6lxcBUWZeSUaRal6aZl5KYk5ORpADToKQCs0Nbn@/wcA)

```
\b(\w+)\b   # match one or more word characters with word boundaries
            # fore and aft and save to capture group 1
(?!         # begin negative lookahead
  .*        # match zero or more characters
  \b\1\b    # match the content of capture group 1 with word boundaries
            # fore and aft
)           # end negative lookahead
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is same As what @anotherGatsby used. Below code snippet gives your required result.

> x=['isaac morka morka']

> str = str(x)

> rex =re.compile('isaac[\s\S]+?morka')

> print(re.findall(rex,str))